# Wordpress - pages stopped working - permalink issues?

Tags: wordpress, menu, permalinks

I developed a simple wordpress site for a company.
Today they called me and said that some of the pages can't be visited.
So i checked it out , and seems like 3 menu options for apparent reason just stopped working. They said they haven't done any changes.

http://oi40.tinypic.com/ofqcev.jpg

Check the permalink it says says "projektledning" like it should be , and wordpress refuses to find the page.

http://oi40.tinypic.com/16h9mcg.jpg

And i tried for no reason to change the permalink and i've added "-1" to the link and bam its working...

What should i do to make the permalink work as the regular name it should be?

Comment: Try toggle permalink once under admin - settings - permalinks. You could also try to delete your `.htaccess` file before doing this, make a backup before trying this though.

Comment: I've tried to set them to default value - and it worked, gonna try if i can work around this!

Comment: What did you use `/%postname%/` before?

Comment: Would be nice if you could post the contents of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I made a backup of my .htacess and deleted the old one , and set permalinks to default, then postname. and voila it worked!

Weird that this problem even occured due to no changes...

Comment: Perhaps the comments will help someone else, so I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try toggle permalink once under `admin - settings - permalinks`. Make sure you're server has write access to your `.htaccess` file before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess should look this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

At the last row, make sure there's a space between . and /
Also check your permalinks for any typos (spaces).

IF your url is foo.bar/something, make your .htaccess look like:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /something/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /something/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Hope this helps!